# How do I create list view of edit texts?

Tags: android, rubymotion

I want to create a layout where there need to be multiple key-value pairs in a list view that the user can edit. I want to programmatically create a layout that looks something like this.

[Title] [Button that adds a row to the list]
[ [EditText for key] [EditText for value] ]
[ [EditText for key] [EditText for value] ]

I'm new to Android development so I'm not sure if nesting EditText views inside a ListView is the correct approach. Also, I'm using RubyMotion, which allows me to write the app in Ruby so that's why I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: You can use a custom listView.

Comment: extend a BaseAdapter and set that adapter to listview.

Comment: you want to get a solution or advice?

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Solution would be fantastic. Advice is great too because I'm a complete noob and there may be better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi But I want to display the EditText view inside the adapter, I don't really have an idea of how to do that.

Comment: I have a solution for you, but it is in Java

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Yeah a solution in Java is great. The main problem I'm facing here is I don't know what to do to get the UI I want. If I know what to do then I'll be able to write it in RubyMotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private LinearLayout root;
        private KeyValueAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /**
     * create content view
     */
            root = new LinearLayout(this);
            root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams rootParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            root.setLayoutParams(rootParams);
            setContentView(root);

    /**
     * create header view (title + button)
     */
            LinearLayout header = new LinearLayout(this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams headerParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            header.setLayoutParams(headerParams);
            header.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText("Some title");
            header.addView(textView);
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText("Add row");
            header.addView(button);
            root.addView(header);

            adapter = new KeyValueAdapter(this);

    /**
     * create list view
     */
            ListView listView = new ListView(this);
            listView.setLayoutParams(rootParams);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            root.addView(listView);

    /**
     * set click listener
     */
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    adapter.addRow();
                }
            });



        }
    }
```

Adapter implementation

```
static class KeyValueAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private List<Entry> data;
        private Context context;

        KeyValueAdapter(Context context) {
            data = new ArrayList<>();
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(context);
            rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            rootView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            final Entry entry = data.get(position);

            EditText keyEditText = new EditText(context);
            keyEditText.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            keyEditText.setHint("Key");
            keyEditText.setText(entry.key);
            keyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    entry.key = s.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            EditText valueEditText = new EditText(context);
            valueEditText.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            valueEditText.setHint("Value");
            valueEditText.setText(entry.value);
            valueEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    entry.value = s.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            rootView.addView(keyEditText);
            rootView.addView(valueEditText);
            return rootView;
        }

        public void addRow(Entry entry){
            data.add(0, entry);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addRow(){
            data.add(0, new Entry("", ""));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Entry as a list item

```
public static class Entry{
        public String key;
        public String value;

        public Entry(String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

I have all of this was in the same file, I divide the class for you

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had something similar except for calling notifyDataSetChanged() at the end of addRow method and I could not have figured that out.